# Laravel: Allow temporary access to part of a site

Tags: laravel, security, authentication

In my Laravel application, the user profile information includes sensitive details such as tax file number and bank account details.  Since the application is used a lot via mobile (and people regularly lose their mobile phone), I have split the user profile into 'financial details' and 'other details'.

If someone wants to access the financial details they must provide the user password.  The route accepts both POST and GET, and here's the controller code:

```
public function showDetails(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return view('staff.finance-info', compact('user'));
        } else {
            $request->session()->flash('auth_failed', 'Password incorrect');
        }
    }

    return redirect()->route('staff.profile');
}
```

I am accepting a GET so that I can gracefully redirect the request to the 'other details' profile.

This works fine for viewing details however I now need to provide routes for updating the info.  (One for bank details, one for tax, etc).  I don't want the user to have to reenter their password on each of these pages.

What would be the typical way to handle this scenario?  By issuing some sort of token, perhaps?  Should I just create a random token and store it as an expiring value in the session?  What other options are there?

Comment: If the form is being visible only after they provide a password then the form should already contain the `csrf` token in it and you don't need another token because the form will not visible to th user if no or wrong password is given and if the form shown then it's been checked and should contain (you should've given) the csrf, isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a session may be name `finance`as `true` afer getting password for view and check subsequent check for its existe ce for view and update.

Set session value here

```
   if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        session("finance",true);
        return view('staff.finance-info', compact('user'));
    } else {
        $request->session()->flash('auth_failed', 'Password incorrect');
    }
```

And check before `view` and `update`. This is for `view`

```
  if(session("finance")){
      $user = Auth::user();
      return view('staff.finance-info', compact('user'));
  }
```

Same check for `update`